# What can i use for create a dynamic web project in eclipse not using Maven?

Tags: spring, hibernate, maven, web

i just want use Spring 4 and Hibernate 4. that's because in my company we don't have internet service for Maven or gradle.

Comment: You can use WTP to build WARs with normal eclipse .project builders.

Comment: Is it that you have no Internet connectivity at the office or that access to Maven central is blocked?

Comment: If your company is Java shop without access to Maven Central repo, there has to be some internal mirror of it. If there isn't, quit your job.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your situation is so sad that you don't have access to any Repository (Maven central nor internal mirror of it), Ant build system (Predecessor of Maven and Gradle) is designed to work with local dependencies.

You would need to download them somehow, push to your source control (hopefully that is available to you) and hook them into Ant.

There is also option to use Bash or Make, but personally wouldn't recommend.